# How to get connection tester result?

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

I need a timer to periodically check the status of a connection in a [ComboPooledDataSource](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html). Is there a way to read its status or to "listen" when the connection check fails (and when it comes up again)?

I have thought about implementing a connection tester ([see documentation](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing)), but since it is instantiated internally (the way to set the connection tester is [through its qualified name](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connectionTesterClassName)):

```java
...
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setConnectionTesterClassName("some.qualified.connection.tester");
...
```

the only solution I see is that it sets some static variable accordingly. I came up with the timer trying to get the connection ([getConnection()](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.html#getConnection--)) and catching the exception:

```java
try {
        cpds.getConnection();
        //it is up
} catch (SQLException e) {
        //it is down
}
```

Any better way to accomplish that?

Comment: what do you mean by "fails to set some class". what is it precisely that might fail, of whose failures you would like to be notified?

Comment: @SteveWaldman, I have edited the question to make it more clear.